# hive concatenate partition all

Tags: hive, concatenation

How to concatenate all partitions in one single command.
for eg , in case to analyze stats , we can run analyze table 'tablename' partition ( 'partition column name' ) compute statistics;
similarly for dropping etc we can run , alter table 'tablename' drop partition ( 'partition column name'  '>/=/< etc' 'value' )

but it seems there is no way to concatenate command for whole partitions in one go.

for now i am generating like hdfs dfs -ls 'hdfs table location' | awk -F '/' '{print "alter table 'tablename' partition ("$NF") concatenate;"}'

is there any way where i can get same output in one command?

Comment: You could get the list of all partitions using the show partition tablename in hive from there you could concantenate the partiion names if you are looking for partiion names alone. Correct me if I understood your question wrongly. Also If you are looking to merge all the partitions data then hadoop fs -merge is the option. Sorry If I misunderstood your question entirely wrong.

Comment: sorry for not making it clear enough. what i have now is a table with 100 partition , and inside each partition i have 150 files ( altogether 100*150 files ) . Now i need to run a command that would merge all files in individual partitions. if the 150 files in each partition gets reduced to 10 files , even that is better for me . But i need to keep files within each partition separately and not merge across partitions. i am looking for a command which would do merge for all partition in one go rather than running one by one for each partitions